# How to access layer using feature service URL/path

Tags: geoprocessing, arcgis-python-api, arcgis-enterprise

I am trying to access a feature layer within my Portal using the layers path. I have been accessing the data within Visual Studio Code using the feature layers ID like this:

```
feature_service_layer = gis.content.get('964b4b7b112347e9ff76609bfc75432').layers[0]
```

I'd like to make a Geoprocessing tool out of the code. The tool would accept the parameter under the format of the URL which would be something along the lines of:  'https://maps.portaladdress.com/arcgis/rest/services/Hosted/Feature_layer/FeatureServer/0'

I have tried to add the URL to the code but it is unsuccessful. Here is what it looked like (I also tried the .Search method):

```py
feature_service_layer = gis.content.get(https://maps.portaladdress.com/arcgis/rest/services/Hosted/Feature_layer/FeatureServer/0)

feature_service_layer = gis.content.search(https://maps.portaladdress.com/arcgis/rest/services/Hosted/Feature_layer/FeatureServer/0)
```

If I can't use these methods how am I supposed to take a feature layer in as a parameter and access its data?

Comment: @user2856 where will it create that feature layer? My default geodatabase within the pro project?

Comment: Layers aren't featureclasses. It'll just make a layer in memory that points at the url. Look at the examples in the documentation 
for  arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer

Answer (score 2):

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer

agol = GIS("home")

url = "https://maps.portaladdress.com/arcgis/rest/services/Hosted/Feature_layer/FeatureServer/0"
fl = FeatureLayer(url, gis=agol)
```